# Visual Studio 2013 Add-Ins for Outlook 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, outlook

Visual Studio 2013.

Outlook 2013

I'm trying to create a button on the Home tab of Outlook2013. Apparently this should be really simple but I'm obviously doing something wrong here as Google tells me it's as simple as setting ControlId.OfficeId to `TabMail`.

I've downloaded the `Office2013FluentUserInterfaceControlIdentifiers.zip` file and checked to see if the tab still has the same name - and it does.

My new tab item is as simple as they come - just a button I've dragged from the toolbox and changed the ControlIdType to `Office` and the OfficeId to `TabMail`

The only tab I can get the button displayed in is the developer tab, if I use `TabDeveloper`. I expected it to appear on the main Developer tab it only appears on the developer tab of a message.

There's not really any code I can post to this question and not sure what else to say.

I'm hoping someone else has had a similar issue and can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st step - find out if the Add In is causing any errors:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx 
>   To show add-in user interface errors
>
> Start the application. (i.e. Outlook)
>
> Click the File tab.
>
> Click Options.
>
> In the categories pane, click Advanced.
>
> In the details pane, select Show add-in user interface errors, and then click OK.
>
> For Outlook, the Show add-in user interface errors checkbox is located in the Developer section of the details pane. For other
>   applications, the checkbox is located in the General section of the
>   details pane.

In my scenario the errors show up as you double click on an email to open it in a separate window:

[image: ErrorMessage]

The weird thing is - the ControlId I'm using appears to be correct according to the file from Microsoft

> Office2013FluentUserInterfaceControlIdentifiers.zip http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36798

After getting nowhere for an hour - I decided to click `Export Ribbon to XML`:

[image: Export Button location]

This creates a `.cs` file and a `.xml` file. The `.cs` file tells you to copy some code from it and pasted it into the ThisAddIn.cs file. Once you do this, the `.xml` file is the master and the designer seems to be ignored - ensure you still have the correct ControlId in the XML `<tab idMso="TabMail">` and it should just work!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabMail">
                <group id="group1" label="group1">
                    <button id="button1" label="Rick" showImage="false" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

[image: Working button]

I'm not sure why I couldn't get the designer working without converting to XML - this is the first time I've ever had to do this. Hopefully this will help someone else who experiences the same issue.